# Is there any way to bulk search-replace URLs that exist within ACF's "Link" field type (serialized)?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

- I have a list of 500+ URLs that need to be searched and replaced
- This is a spreadsheet with two columns, the match URL and the replacement URL
- I've been using `wp search-replace --all-tables 'foo' 'bar'` to update most URLs
- However, I've noticed an issue with URLs that exist within ACF's "Link" field type. I think these URLs aren't being replaced because they are serialized
- I know interconnectit's [Search-Replace-DB](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) is usually suggested for more thorough search and replaces, although I don't see any option to bulk run this

*Note to StackExchange mods - the ACF forum registration is not working at the moment so I cannot ask there.*

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally verified this but I had these [two commands saved](https://github.com/wp-cli/search-replace-command/issues/45#issuecomment-554566809) using WP-CLI which uses some clever regular expressions when I run into this scenario.